# str_contains returns true, but preg_match returns false

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents

I am getting the HTML code of this website -

> https://theatrevazrajdane.bg/%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%8A%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8/2

with this code `$html = file_get_contents($url)`

and then I am running a simple regex which does not work and I have no idea why.

This code output - FALSE

```
preg_match('/actor/miu', $html);
```

and this code output - TRUE

```
str_contains($html, 'actor');
```

Do you know where it could be the reason I checked the HTML several times. It is the correct HTML.

Comment: Adjust the modifier to `/actor/i`.

Comment: You might want to check possible problems with the `u` modifier at https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page  has problems with unicode.

Try `preg_match('/actor/mi', $html);`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please just explain in this case what is the difference between having the u and without it. I know it is for the unicode chars, but why this code with `/miu` is failing? Thanks

Comment: The `m` modifier is also useless.